# What should be the interface for Fowler's Observation?

Tags: oop

In *Analysis Patterns*, Fowler describes how to deal with clinical observations that can either be a measurement of a numeric value, or a categorical observation (absence or presence of symptoms, sex, etc). Here is the relevant diagram:

[image]

This diagram suggests that `Observation` should be some kind of common interface for `Measurement` and `Category Observation`. But I can't see how this can be done in a strongly typed language. Suppose, for example, that I want to iterate over all `Observation`s made on a `Person`, and do something different depending on whether they are `Measurement`s or `Category Observation`, how can I avoid trickery such as testing for the object's type, casting, etc?

Comment: Someone with 11.5k rep should know why this has been flagged by myself for closure

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is this (and I maybe wrong) . Both Quantity and Category derive from a common interface (maybe called ObservationParameter) , this interface has APIs to deal with data that is encapsulated by the underlying type (for example evaluate or compare, pardon my lack of knowledge for the domain). Therefore, while iterating over persons , you just fetch observation.getObservationParameter().evaluate() (.. or something like that).  This way you are still working with the abstract types without the need for casts or checks. The appropriate numerical or categorical logic will be implemented by the concrete implementations of Quantity and Category respectively.